# Listing permutations of two dice with one loop

Tags: c++, algorithm

As part of a coding challenge for myself, I've been trying to write code for simple problems in one line. Currently, I'm trying to print out all permutations possible for two dice. So far, I have a simple algorithm utilizing two for loops:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
    for(int j = i; j <= 6; j++)
        printf("%d %d", i, j);
```

Which can be easily turned into one line:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) for(int j = i; j <= 6; j++) printf("%d %d", i, j);
```

Both programs output the permutations in the desired order:

```
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
2 2
2 3
2 4
2 5
2 6
3 3
3 4
3 5
3 6
4 4
4 5
4 6
5 5
5 6
6 6
```

In order to make this challenge harder, I'm trying to print out the permutations in the same order as the output above, using **only one loop**. I'm sure I'll need to use division and modulo in order to accomplish this, but I'm stuck and unsure how to achieve this.

Comment: Note: The path you seem to have chosen is that of the dark side. One should strive to write code that is easy to read, understand, and maintain, not cramped and cryptic. Only complicate code if you have to in order to meet performance requirements.

Comment: FYI, whitespace is for humans.  The compiler doesn't need whitespace (except some symbol separation rules).  Must read: [International Obfuscated C Code Contest](https://www.ioccc.org/).  There is no benefit, speed or space, for eliminating whitespace.  It's still the same code as far as the compiler is concerned.

Comment: What about this: `for(int i = 0; i < 36; i++) printf("%d %d\n", (i/6)+1, (i%6)+1 );`  It uses divide and modulus like you were expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 2 loop version is the most readable. But since you asked, here are some 1 loop versions:

```
int main()
{
    int n = 6;
    for (int i = 1, j = 1; i < n; ++j) 
    {
        if (j > n)
        {
            ++i;
            j = i;
        }
        std::cout << i << " " << j << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << std::flush;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    int n = 6;
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        if (j > n)
        {
            ++i;
            j = i;
        }
        if (i > n)
        {
            break;
        }
        std::cout << i << " " << j << '\n';
        ++j;
    }
    std::cout << std::flush;
}
```

---

As a side note:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) for(int j = i; j <= 6; j++) printf("%d %d", i, j);
```

This is horrible. Don't ever write code like this. The artificial goal of writing code in one line is completely and utterly pointless. You can take any code and put it on one line like that without any effort so it has absolutely not benefit, teaching or otherwise.

There is the concept of writing one-liners but that is not just replacing new lines in source code with spaces. It's about e.g. replacing loops with function calls or chain calls.

And don't forget, first and foremost write correct, clean and readable code.

Comment: This lists combinations for the two dice, I'm trying to list permutations.

Comment: @PolarisEmperor right, edited.

Comment: Thanks for the solution and tips, I'll be sure to prioritize readability when writing code!